# toggle contentEditable on and off inside React function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react function that puts out a div. This div is a draggable, and it should also be editable. I have tried using contentEditable, which makes the div editable when set to 'true', but then i can no longer drag the item, only edit it.

Is there a way to make the div "editability" to toggle on and off, for example using an onclick to turn contentEditable to 'on', and a doubleClick to turn contentEditable to 'true', enabling the dragging?

```
return (
    <div
        onDoubleClick contentEditable={true} // needs to be toggleable, in some way

        ref={provided.innerRef}
        {...provided.draggableProps}
        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
        {item.content};
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it with hooks.  I assume you are using them.

```
const [contentEditable, setContentEditable] = React.useState(false)

return (
    <div
        onDoubleClick={()=> setContentEditable(!contentEditable)}

        ref={provided.innerRef}
        {...provided.draggableProps}
        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
        {item.content};
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I am not using hooks, and this blows up : / sorry but i really appreciate your help!

Comment: What error are you getting when you add this example into your code?  Do you have this in a repo you can share?  I'm happy to take a look.

Or you could paste your implementation of this answer here so we can make sure you or I don't have any typos in it.

Comment: For a good answer, your questions needs more context.  Does the boolean that indicates if the content is editable need to be accessed in another component?  If it does, this example will not work.

Comment: https://github.com/vinceparis95/stem/tree/master/portal/scslime, in src/App.js. contentEditable is set on line 142. Thanks again! And youre right, i guess i was having trouble describing this particular context (noob to all front end stuff).

Comment: Hope the git helps to provide some context!

Comment: I got it to work.  Look at line 110 and lines 197-200.  The console.log on line 112 shows the boolean changing onDoubleClick.

If you could remove the down vote that would be appreciated 

https://github.com/adamhinckley/stem/blob/master/portal/scslime/src/App.js

Comment: awesome ! removed the downer. Last thing, when i edit and add some text, and then move it across columns, the text now vanishes.

Comment: You'll need to find a way to preserve that text in state.  That is a separate issue from the question asked here.  If you can't figure it out after trying to preserve it in state, ask a separate question and provide as much detail as possible.